# What cable is this, and what is attached to the end?

Tags: identification, connector, function-generator, transducer

I have a question regarding the cable in a red square, namely that green thing.

This is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-E7zlQEk5MA&list=FLGiddkKBevWZO7L_i0ddMGw&ab_channel=LindsayWilson) from YouTube and I am trying to recreate the same. I want to connect the same type of transducer to the function generator. Could you please advise on it?

[image: Screenshot from YouTube]

Comment: It looks like a connector and nothing more exotic than that.

Answer (score 2):

The 'green thing' is merely a connector of some description, possibly for 'Lucas' style flat terminals. The video author does not have the corresponding connector, as he is hooking a croc-clip lead and a 'scope probe to it. They can also be made to work tolerably for temporary hookup with a leaded resistor stuffed into it, as is demonstrated in that photo.

If you want a better guess on that green thing, then you need a higher resolution photo of it.

Comment: Here is a photo of what is probably its mating connector, found through a link in the video description: http://imajeenyus.com/electronics/20110514_power_ultrasonic_driver/photos/DSCN4076.JPG Looks to be some Phoenix type connector.

Comment: @Klas-Kenny at the beginning of the video there is a schema of electrical circuit, and I suppose it a load, but I am not sure as I have never seen it before

Answer (score 0):

> namely that green thing.

That green connector is [the plug of a 2-piece pluggable terminal block](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?sm=N&nm=N&bm=K&c=terminal_blocks&u=pluggable_terminal_blocks&o=two_pc_terminal_blocks) (my site).

[image]

> I want to connect the same type of transducer to the function generator.

If the transducer has a  plug of a 2-piece pluggable terminal block, you will need the matching male connectors for it. Such connectors are available for PCB mount for wire-to-board connections, as well as with wire terminals for wire-to-wire connections. Tell us which you prefer.

To identify the exact part, we need you to have that plug in your hands so you can a) take a better picture of it and post it, and b) measure and tell us its exact [pitch](https://www.google.com/search?q=connector+pitch).

Comment: I found this [picture](http://imajeenyus.com/electronics/20110514_power_ultrasonic_driver/20170222/1.jpg). It is a high-quality picture of the entire system I am trying to construct.

Comment: " I am trying to construct.". Do you already have the sensor? If yes, we need pictures and pitch of the connector at the end of the sensor. If not, come back to us _after_ you have the sensor. No sense in wasting time on something that you don't yet have